# SQL IF and ELSE block with temp tables inside

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, reporting-services, temp-tables

I got a quite big query with `CTEs`, `temp` tables and I'd like to put it into `IF` and `ELSE` blocks, for having different conditions for both of them, depend on parameter. In simplified it looks as below:

```
DECLARE @parameter varchar(15)

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #table1
End
create table #table1
(
column1
column2
column3
)

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table2') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #table2
End
create table #table2
(
column1
column2
column3
)

IF @parameter = 'Option1' BEGIN
select * from (

INSERT INTO #table1
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option1'
INSERT INTO #table2
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option1'

select * from #table1
union all
select * from #table2) as DATA
  END ELSE

IF @parameter = 'Option2' BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM
(
INSERT INTO #table1
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option2'
INSERT INTO #table2
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option2'

select * from #table1
union all
select * from #table2)
as DATA
  END
```

I put the `#temp` tables at the beginning and it fixed a part of issues, but I still got:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Is this any way how to make this work?

Comment: You cannot make `INSERT` inside `FROM` section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this ?

```
IF @parameter = 'Option1' BEGIN

INSERT INTO #table1
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option1'
INSERT INTO #table2
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option1'

select * from (

select * from #table1
union all
select * from #table2) as DATA
END 
ELSE

IF @parameter = 'Option2' BEGIN

INSERT INTO #table1
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option2'
INSERT INTO #table2
select * from... where 'condition_for_Option2'
SELECT *
FROM
(
select * from #table1
union all
select * from #table2)
as DATA
END
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not have `insert` statement in `select` statement. Actualy you can rewrite:

```
IF @parameter = 'Option1' 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #table1
    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option1'
    INSERT INTO #table2
    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option1'

    SELECT * FROM #table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM #table2

END 

ELSE IF @parameter = 'Option2' 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #table1
    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option2'
    INSERT INTO #table2
    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option2'

    SELECT * FROM #table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM #table2

END
```

but I can't see any usage of temp table here, so you can rewrite:

```
IF @parameter = 'Option1' 
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option1'

END 

ELSE IF @parameter = 'Option2' 
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM... WHERE 'condition_for_Option2'

END
```

Comment: Yep this is correct, but I need Temp Tables because of some other needs (as I mentioned that was simplified query). But thank you anyway, the first one will work for me.